# Using remote image in ImageMagick with Node.JS

Tags: node.js, imagemagick

How can I use remote image in ImageMagick with Node.JS?

I want to achieve something like:

```
im.identify('http://www.website.com/image.jpg', function(error, features) {
    console.log(features);
});
```

Comment: Please, provide more information—step-by-step of this process as you imagine.

Comment: For example:
`im.identify('http://www.website.com/image.jpg', function(error, features) {
  console.log(features);
});`
Doesnt work because its a remote file so I would like to find a solution :)

Answer (score 3):

**A quick code snippet of image resizing**

http://nodejs.org/api/http.html
https://github.com/rsms/node-imagemagick

```
var thumb = '';

...

var request = http.get(options, function(response) {

    var data = '';

    response.setEncoding('binary');

    response.on('data', function(chunk) {
        data += chunk;
    });

    response.on('end', function () {

        im.resize({
            srcData: data,
            width: 100,
            height: 75,
            format: 'jpg'
        }, function(err, stdout, stderr) {
            if (err) throw err;
            thumb = stdout;
        });
    }

});
```

Comment: You don't need to save the image on disk.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I use remote images:

```
var srcUrl = 'http://domain.com/path/to/image.jpg';
var http = srcUrl.charAt(4) == 's' ? require("https") : require("http");
var url = require("url");

http.get(url.parse(srcUrl), function(res) {

    if(res.statusCode !== 200) {
        throw 'statusCode returned: ' + res.statusCode;
    }
    else {
        var data = new Array;
        var dataLen = 0;

        res.on("data", function (chunk) {
            data.push(chunk);
            dataLen += chunk.length;
        });

        res.on("end", function () {
            var buf = new Buffer(dataLen);
            for(var i=0,len=data.length,pos=0; i<len; i++) {
                data[i].copy(buf, pos);
                pos += data[i].length;
            }

            im(buf).imFunctionYouWantToUse();
        });
    }
});
```

Credit go to https://stuk.github.io/jszip/documentation/howto/read_zip.html

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say if i understood you correctly (considering the amount of information you posted here).

The only way you can perform operations on a remote image using imagemagick is to download it to the local server first. This can be done using the [http.ClientRequest](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.6/api/http.html#http.ClientRequest) class of node.js, afterwards you should be able to operate on the image as usual using Imagemagick.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
var request = require('request');
var fs = require('fs');

request({
        'url': 'http://www.website.com/image.jpg',
        'encoding':'binary'
    }, 
    function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            fs.writeFileSync('/mylocalpath/image.jpg', body, 'binary');
            im.identify('/mylocalpath/image.jpg',
                function(error, features) {
                    console.log(features);
                 }
            );
        }else{
            console.error(error, response);
        }
    }
)
```